# Why to use #define macro name is simply used in c code?

Tags: c

I see in one c code that the macro name is simply used in it as below. What is the intention behind it? What is the use?

```
#define PORTING_SECTION_BEGIN
#define PORTING_SECTION_END
int a;
...
PORTING_SECTION_BEGIN
void foo() {
int d=10;
PORTING_SECTION_END
...
```

Why we need to use PORTING_SECTION_BEGIN & PORTING_SECTION_END ? Is it just for identification?

Comment: If that is all there is, it is to mark that portion of the code for some other software or a person to find. Another possibility is this was generated code and, in some other circumstances, the `#define` directives would include additional code triggering certain compiler features.

Comment: I suspect they use this so they can search for these blocks in the code. Although comments would be a better way, IMHO.

Comment: Maybe there are some alternative definitions of the same macros elsewhere, which do expand to something else for specific configuration?

Comment: @Barmar Comments would work, but wouldn't detect typos.

Comment: `one c code` What C code exactly? From where? Who wrote it? Where is it available? What else is in the code? Can you post a link? Can you post full source? How and where from did you get it? Who distributed it and how?

Comment: You'll need to ask this to the person who wrote the code. Others can just speculate.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is mostly speculation.

It's fairly obvious that the names `PORTING_SECTION_BEGIN` and `PORTING_SECTION_END` are being used to mark certain chunks of code, presumably code that needs to be modified when porting the program to another platform. They appear to be just markers.

Since the macros expand to nothing, removing the macro definitions and references would effectively not change the code -- at least as far as the C compiler is concerned.

These markers seem to be mostly for the benefit of the reader/maintainer of the code. There may also be some outside tool that does something with these markers.

Comments are another obvious way to do this kind of thing, but by using macro names (with the `#define` lines perhaps being added automatically), the compiler can detect misspellings.

This is probably a project-specific technique, not one that's generally used. A Google search for "PORTING_SECTION_BEGIN" got exactly one hit: this question.

C# has a language-defined `#region` construct. This looks very similar.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the existing answer that these macros are most likely markers which could be found in the code easily. But consider another explanation (or idea which you could use): you can easily change the definition of the macros back and forth.

You could add logging and see how many times the specific parts of code have been executed.

If your system has special code directives (like "put code into a specific section in the executable" or "optimize to a specific architecture"), you could easily make experiments to check how various directives affect your program.

---

Yet another possibility: your task is to port a lot of code. You mark lines you have ported (and tested); some tool examines your code and sees how much work is left to do.

However, comments would work for that just fine.